# Verbose and/or Debug Output from Rust Borrow Checker

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, ownership

Is there some way to get verbose output from the Rust borrow checker to see its logic for each source file?  When there's some kind of problem with lifetimes and/or borrows, it sometimes produces some really helpful output explaining the problem.  Is there a way to get something similar when there's not a problem?

The specific case I'm interested in right now comes from the Rust Async book (https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/02_execution/02_future.html):

```
        if let Some(a) = &mut self.a {
            if let Poll::Ready(()) = a.poll(wake) {
                self.a.take();
            }
        }
```

This compiles successfully, but I'm not entirely clear on how.  It seems like you're matching on a mutable reference to `self.a`, so that reference needs to be live for the entire block, but inside the block, you call `take`, which requires another mutable reference to `self.a`.

I'm interested in how this specific case works out, but I also want to be able to trace through similar cases.  It seems like there's got to be somewhere in the compiler where the borrow checker checks a series of boolean conditions and it would be really nice if you could dump some kind of log to a file.  Is there any way to do something like this?

Comment: As for this specific case: the `a` binding (and therefore the mutable borrow that it required) is no longer used and can therefore be released as soon as `a.poll()` has been called; if you used `a` again after the `if` statement, or indeed after the call to `self.a.take()`, you'd have a problem.

Comment: As for the more general question, I don't think there's anything that's easily accessible.  The borrow checker operates on rustc's MIR, but that's quite different to the source code with which you'll be familiar (you can view the MIR for your project by providing the `--emit mir` argument); and you can have rustc produce graphic visualisations of lifetime scope within the MIR with, for example, the `#[rustc_mir(borrowck_graphviz_postflow="suffix.dot")]` attribute—but it's very much an internal feature intended for compiler testing/debugging and is unlikely to be meaningful to end users...